# Flutter custom image collage

Tags: image, flutter, dart, widget, custom-painting

I would like to be able to build *collages* and for that I tried using `CustomPaint` to draw the shape and then filling that shape with an `image`. This is what I tried:

```
  Container(
    height: 300,
    width: 300,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 5),
    ),
    child: CustomPaint(
      painter: DrawTriangleShape(color: Colors.blue),
      child: Image.asset('assets/images/exampleImage.jpg'),
    ),
  ),
```

And my `DrawTriangleShape`:

```
class DrawTriangleShape extends CustomPainter {
  Paint painter;

  DrawTriangleShape({color: Colors}) {
    painter = Paint()
      ..color = color
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var path = Path();

    path.moveTo(size.width / 1, 0);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.height, size.width);
    path.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path, painter);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

The outcome:

[image]

As you can see it is not really the desired outcome as the image is not filling the shape. I didn't find anything on this. Is it even possible? And if not, what would be the best approach to build collages with custom shapes?

Let me know if you need more info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a `CustomPaint`, use a `ClipPath` widget.

Using the same path as your `CustomPaint`:

[image]

#### Full source code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ClipPath(
          clipper: CustomClipperImage(),
          child: Image.asset('images/abstract.jpg'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomClipperImage extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  getClip(Size size) {
    return Path()
      ..moveTo(size.width / 1, 0)
      ..lineTo(0, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.height, size.width)
      ..close();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

---

### Additional example with a white border and scaling the image.

[image]

#### Full source code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .8;
    final height = width * .7;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.black54,
        child: Center(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              CustomPaint(
                painter: MyPainter(),
                child: Container(width: width, height: height),
              ),
              ClipPath(
                clipper: CustomClipperImage(),
                child: Transform.scale(
                  scale: 3,
                  child: Image.asset('images/abstract.jpg',
                      width: width, height: height),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomClipperImage extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  getClip(Size size) {
    return Path()
      ..moveTo(size.width, 0)
      ..lineTo(0, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.height, size.height)
      ..close();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final path = Path()
      ..moveTo(size.width, 0)
      ..lineTo(0, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.height, size.height)
      ..close();
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..strokeWidth = 8.0
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

---

### Solution with zoom and pan on the image

Using a `GestureDetector` to detect the change of `scale` and `localFocalPoint`. And then using a `Matrix4` to `Transform` our `Image.asset`:

[image]

#### Full source code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .8;
    final _height = _width * .6;
    final _zoom = useState<double>(1.0);
    final _previousZoom = useState<double>(1.0);
    final _offset = useState<Offset>(Offset.zero);
    final _previousOffset = useState<Offset>(Offset.zero);
    final _startingFocalPoint = useState<Offset>(Offset.zero);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.black54,
        child: Center(
          child: GestureDetector(
            onScaleStart: (details) {
              _startingFocalPoint.value = details.localFocalPoint;
              _previousOffset.value = _offset.value;
              _previousZoom.value = _zoom.value;
            },
            onScaleUpdate: (details) {
              _zoom.value = _previousZoom.value * details.scale;
              final Offset normalizedOffset =
                  (_startingFocalPoint.value - _previousOffset.value) /
                      _previousZoom.value;
              _offset.value =
                  details.localFocalPoint - normalizedOffset * _zoom.value;
            },
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                CustomPaint(
                  painter: MyPainter(),
                  child: Container(width: _width, height: _height),
                ),
                ClipPath(
                  clipper: CustomClipperImage(),
                  child: Transform(
                    transform: Matrix4.identity()
                      ..translate(_offset.value.dx, _offset.value.dy)
                      ..scale(_zoom.value),
                    // ..rotateZ(_rotation.value),
                    child: Image.asset('images/milkyway.jpg',
                        width: _width, height: _height),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomClipperImage extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  getClip(Size size) {
    return Path()
      ..moveTo(size.width, 0)
      ..lineTo(0, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.height, size.height)
      ..close();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final path = Path()
      ..moveTo(size.width, 0)
      ..lineTo(0, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.height, size.height)
      ..close();
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..strokeWidth = 8.0
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! But another thing: is there a way to move the image around / zoom the image in and out ? Inside the frame

Comment: And there should be a white border on the frame, is that possible with clip path?

Comment: border is as expected, awesome! But the scaling is not working for me?

Comment: >> *But the scaling is not working for me.*  I'm not sure I understand what you want, in fact.

Comment: fair enough :D I mean zooming into the picture, with gestures. Also moving it around inside that canvas. Does that make sense?

Comment: OIC. Check my update. It will probably require some tweaking. Good night!

Comment: damn. Youre good :D thanks! will work on this next week and probably have some questions about it, cy

Comment: Hi Thierry, so I implemented your solution but there is another thing, when zooming, the image should remain its position and should only be scaled. any idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: Ooops, my bad, I was using `focalPoint` instead of `localFocalPoint`. That's why the image was slowly translating when zooming in and out. Check my update.

Comment: good to know that! working as expected now, thanks again :)

Comment: any way to make this also draggable ?:D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66474773/flutter-make-image-with-gesturedetectors-also-draggable